# Test actor in akka by java and have ActorInitializationException

Tags: java, exception, testing, akka, actor

I want using from  actor test in create actor sample code.but by run actor test throws ActorInitializationException. my goal is see testing goals by actor test and i am using junit test but
my class code in under:

```
public class Worker extends AbstractActor {

private ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("worker");;
private Props props = Props.create(Worker.class , system.guardian().toString());
private ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(props);

@Override
public void preStart() {
    System.out.println("worker actor started");
}

@Override
public void postStop() {
    System.out.println("worker actor stopped");
}



@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
            .matchAny(x -> getSender().tell(x, getSelf()))
            .build();
}


@Test
public void testMain() throws Exception {
    Future sFuture = ask(actor, "ping" , 1000);
    System.out.println("First : " + sFuture);

}
```

}

```
and when running test method in up code this exception occur:

akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [akka.worker.Worker] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.

at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:192)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.$init$(Actor.scala:467)
at akka.actor.AbstractActor.<init>(AbstractActor.scala:132)
at ir.dotin.alm.akka.worker.Worker.<init>(Worker.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
```

Comment: How do you start this actor in your tests? Have you seen Java documentation on Akka Actor testing? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/testing.html

Comment: i am start with definition actor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: You wrote the test inside the actor. Junit tries to instantiate the class containing the tests with `new()`, thus failing it. Try splitting the definitions:

```
public class Worker extends AbstractActor {

  @Override
  public void preStart() {
      System.out.println("worker actor started");
  }

  @Override
  public void postStop() {
      System.out.println("worker actor stopped");
  }



  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
      return receiveBuilder()
              .matchAny(x -> getSender().tell(x, getSelf()))
              .build();
  }
}
```

and then, ***in another file***:

```
public class MyTest() {
  private ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("worker");;
  private Props props = Props.create(Worker.class , system.guardian().toString());
  private ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(props);

  @Test
  public void testMain() throws Exception {
    Future sFuture = ask(actor, "ping" , 1000);
    System.out.println("First : " + sFuture);
  }
}
```

Comment: tanks for your answer . split test class